# Android Alarm Manager repeating in not accurate time interval

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I need my alarm to fire every 30 seconds - exactly as possible (+/-3 seconds). So I read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) (official Android guide) and implemented this:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30000, pendingIntent);
```

Result: The Alarm fires +/- every 50 seconds, which is not so much accurate if I gave interval of 30 seconds.

Where is the problem and what's going on here? In the documentation they say things about be careful with exact timers since cpu & battery consuming etc. but nevertheless still there is an option for exact if I want, and this is what I thought I implemented.

Comment: Well, for one, `setRepeating()` is inexact since KitKat. You need to use `setExact()`, setting the alarm again each time it fires. Also, for an interval that short, you probably don't want to use `AlarmManager` anyway.

Comment: What you suggest instead of AlaramManager?

Comment: The page you linked has the suggestion: "__Note:__ For timing operations that are guaranteed to occur during the lifetime of your application, instead consider using the [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class in conjunction with [`Timer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [`Thread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html). This approach gives Android better control over system resources."

Comment: @MikeM.  The point is I need to execute the repeating task also if the app is not in the foreground and even if the device is sleep. This is also why I trigger Service and not activity - every 30 seconds wake up some background service no matter what is the status of the device, and perform some logic. Handler is good only for UI context.

Comment: "Handler is good only for UI context." - That's not quite correct, but I think I get what you're saying. In any case, using exact alarms, as opposed to inexact, isn't the main concern. Doing anything every 30 seconds, or thereabouts, is going to kill your battery pretty quickly. If you really, really need to do that, then you can try using `setExact()` as described above. Another option might be to use a `Service` that has a permanent `WakeLock` with the setup suggested in the note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (2 * 1000), (30 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

change delay 2 or up seconds for start alarm on firt time.